# Check scopes of GitHub token

Tags: rest, github, access-token, github-api

I want to passively check the permissions (scopes) of a GitHub security token passively (without pushing something into a repository). I tried the following command. I replaced your_username: your access token and the URL of my repo. But it shows an error.

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

```
curl -u your_username:your_access_token \
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
 https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/collaborators/USERNAME/permission
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Answer (score 10):

If the goal is to determine which scopes a token has access to, check the response header with prefix `x-oauth-scopes` (using `curl` with `-I`):

```
$ GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_DefineYourOwnToken
$ curl -sS -f -I -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" https://api.github.com | grep ^x-oauth-scopes: | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr -d "[:space:]" | tr ',' '\n'
```

Note that `tr -d "[:space:]"` above is essential for removing some unusual whitespace, failing which a matching command such as `grep -x` doesn't subsequently work correctly.

Sample output 1:

```
gist
repo
workflow
```

Sample output 2:

```
delete:packages
public_repo
read:packages
repo:invite
repo:status
```

---

*Credit: [answer by VK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58572011/)*

Comment: this is not working for me my tocket in github actions gets no result back, so no permissions...

Comment: It seems this is simply not yet implemented for fine grained tokens: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/36441#discussioncomment-4838839