# How can I list scopes for Bitbucket app password?

Tags: curl, bitbucket

How do I **list the scopes that my [Bitbucket app password](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/) has access to**? For example, I can then know if it has access to the `repository:admin` scope or not.

I checked the API doc for the [`/user`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-users/#api-user-get) endpoint, but it doesn't return me this info:

```
$ curl -u <username>:<app_password> https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user | jq
```

Is there an endpoint or any other way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to determine which scopes a token has access to, check the response header with prefix `x-oauth-scopes` (using `curl` with `-I`):

```
$ curl -sS -f -I -u <username>:<app_password> https://api.bitbucket.org/ | grep ^x-oauth-scopes: | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr -d "[:space:]" | tr ',' '\n'
```

Note that `tr -d "[:space:]"` above is essential for removing some unusual whitespace, failing which a matching command such as `grep -x` doesn't subsequently work correctly.

Sample output:

```
account
repository:admin
repository:delete
```

---

*Credit: [answer for GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70588035/)*